# AWS CLI not working in Cygwin

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, cygwin, aws-cli

I am working on a Windows computer and have been using Git Bash up until now without a problem. However, Git Bash seems to be missing some commands that Cygwin can provide, so I switched to Cygwin.

I need to use AWS CLI with Cygwin but any time I input any aws command, I get the following error:

> C:\users\myusername\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python.exe:
>   can't open file
>   '/cygdrive/c/Users/myusername/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/Scripts/aws':
>   [Errno 2] No such file or directory

I've seen other questions about getting Cygwin working with AWS, but they seem to talk about AWS CLI being incompatible with Windows' Anaconda version of Python (which mine doesn't seem to be). Any thoughts on how to fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing cygwin posix path with with a not cygwin Python.

`C:\users\myusername\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python.exe`

Is not the cygwin python so it can't open the file as

`/cygdrive/c/Users/myusername/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/Scripts/aws` is not a windows path that it can understand . Only Cygwin programs understand it.

Two possible solutions:
1 Use a windows path
2 Use a cygwin Python

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I spent ages trying to do this as well because I wanted to get setup on the fast.ai course. Nothing seemed to work. However, I uninstalled Anaconda3 and installed Anaconda2 instead. That did the trick!